Making ReID work with BoTSORT object tracking
Am trying BoT-SORT repo.
I tried following commands to try out ReID on my custom 15 seconds video with three people walking, getting occluded behind two trees and emerge back from behind tree.
Single class yolox:
 python3 tools/demo.py video \
 --path <my-video-path> \
 -f yolox/exps/example/mot/yolox_x_mix_det.py \
 -c pretrained/bytetrack_x_mot17.pth.tar \
 --with-reid --fuse-score --fp16 --fuse --save_result

Multiclass with yolox:
 python3 tools/mc_demo.py video \
 --path <my-video-path> \
 -f yolox/exps/example/mot/yolox_x_mix_det.py \
 -c pretrained/bytetrack_x_mot17.pth.tar \
 --with-reid --fuse-score --fp16 --fuse --save_result

Multiclass with yolov7:
python3 tools/mc_demo_yolov7.py 
--weights pretrained/yolov7.pt 
--source <my-video-path>
--fuse-score --agnostic-nms --with-reid

However, none work. When people emerge back from behind the trees after seven of seconds of walk, they are not assigned the older IDs but get assigned newer IDs.
I also tried with options --track_buffer 500 --appearance_thresh 0.05 --proximity_thresh 0, but no luck:
python3 tools/mc_demo_yolov7.py 
--weights pretrained/yolov7.pt 
--source <my-video-path>
--fuse-score --agnostic-nms --with-reid
--track_buffer 500 --appearance_thresh 0.05 --proximity_thresh 0

Are above commands correct? or am doing something wrong here?
